# When does the Feed action request limit refresh?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, limit, facebook-wall

Our users can invite their friends to our app by posting to their friends' walls. Some users have gotten really excited and invited hundreds of their friends (woohoo!), but we're constantly getting the "(#341) Feed action request limit reached" Oauth error and these never make it to any walls (argh).

I know FB limits the posts per user per day (I can see we're limited to 30/user/day in my insights page and the first 30 that were sent seem to go out) but it's been over 36 hours since the last post and I'm still getting "Feed action request limit reached" Oauth errors.

Should the limit have reset at this point? Is there a way to see if they're being blocked because FB thinks they're spam?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll probably get disconnected by anti spam systems if you're using wall posts as an invite mechanism - posts like that get blocked and removed quite a lot by the target users.

To answer your question, the feed action limit is a rolling window as far as i know, so doesn't reset after 24 hours exactly - if the API call fails just wait and try again later - I don't think using the Feed Dialog is subject to the same limits because it's manually approved by the user instead of just being up to the app to ensure policy compliance

Comment: I guess I'm confused about what a "rolling window" is if after 24 hours I'm still not cleared. Is it more than 24 hours? The feed dialog is a little less ideal, but if there's no limitations we'll take a look at that one!